# How to display Tamil content form mysql database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having problem for viewing the Tamil content which retrive from mysql database using CodeIgniter. but the same code is working in core php. i have attached my code below. please check my code and give answer if any changes.

this is my view code:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                 </tr>
                </thead>
                 <tbody>
                          <?php

                               foreach ($per_results as $result)
                               {

                               ?>
    <tr class="">

                               <td><?php echo $result->title;?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $result->description;?></td>
   </tr>
    <?php
                               }
                               ?>

                          </tbody>

                </table>
```

This is my Controller COde:

```
   public function view_mainhome()
    {
      $data['per_results'] = $this->Login_model->getview_permission();
      $this->load->view('forest_add/view_mainhome',$data);
    }
```

This is my Model Code:

```
        function getview_permission() //Stock
        {   
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('forest_permission');
        $this->db->order_by("per_id", "asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
        }
```

Thanks @

Comment: when i changed my SQL column datatype to utf8_general_ci it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks James its working

Comment: You are welcome bro...

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Please try this code in your document header. I hope this will work for Tamil language.

Comment: It is not working. same as from previous... document header means where i want to apply the code.

Comment: Please add this line to head of the view file. not inside body.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment,

Change datatype of SQL column to **utf8_general_ci**

Answer (score 1):

using following mysqli function to we can achieve this 100% worked

```
 config['set_charset']=array( $db, 'utf8');
```

replace $db instead your db connection variable.

Answer (score 0):

@user3839366 `utf8_general_ci` is the collation, make sure you have the same collation for other table fields which you join and compare.

I'm leaving this for anyone else having the utf8 issues. If you have unicode characters, you can do this while creating the table,

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table_name` (
....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or later

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

with specific collation

```
CREATE TABLE `your_table_name` (
....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

or later

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

note:- You can use `utf8mb4` if you want full unicode support (eg, store an emoji in your db)

Also if you want to see the result in console, run `set names utf8;` (also for programs or scripts that do not have out of the box unicode support)