# How do i insert telugu characters into mysql using php?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, xampp

inserting telugu characters as category

[image]

But It Shows Like This

[image]

Comment: I believe that the following should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198701/storing-and-displaying-unicode-string-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%80-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: It is probably a good idea though to share more context about what you are doing. How are you interfacing with mysql?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/43449998/4677060

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing same issue for `UTF-8 characters`, Everything was working on live server and staging server, but sometime it's breaking on my dev machine. The behavior was so strange, some times characters was encoded properly but on random page reload it was start breaking with `Diamond Charters` **`'���เห็นอเวิลด์!���'`** or `Question mark` **`'??�เห็นอเวิลด์!???'`** or 85% data was rendering properly **`'เห็นอเวิลด์!?��'`** but rest 15% was showing unmatched characters. I was looking to fix the issue. So, started with my checklist

> **1 - Check if Character Header Added in HTML**

---

> **2 - Check if data proper saved in MySQL table**

---

> **3 - Check if MySQL has proper encoding settings for UTF-8**

---

> **4 - Check if Apache has Setting to deal with UTF-8 Character set**

---

> **5 - Check if simple PHP can echo "เห็นอเวิลด์" output same as input "เห็นอเวิลด์"**

---

> **6 - Check if PHP sending proper Headers output**

---

> **7 - Check if MySQL Query getting same data "เห็นอเวิลด์"**

---

> **8 - Check if "เห็นอเวิลด์" has some html characters, deal with them properly**

---

> **9 - Check if "เห็นอเวิลด์" passing through any html encode decode function**

---

> **10- Check if .htaccess all set to deal with UTF-8 Character set**

---

> Check all the above list to figure out where something..breaking.

**Give a try (I am using Codeigniter):**

```
=================================
:: PHP ini Settings::
=================================

default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6 

=================================
:: .htaccess Settings::
=================================

DefaultLanguage en-US
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

=================================
:: HTML Header Page::
=================================

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

=================================
:: PHP Codeigniter index.php ::
=================================

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

=================================
:: Codeigniter config.php ::
=================================

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

=================================
:: Codeigniter database.php ::
=================================

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

=================================
:: Codeigniter helper function (optional)
=================================

if(!function_exists('safe_utf_string')){
    function safe_utf_string($utf8string= ''){
        $utf8string = htmlspecialchars($utf8string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        return mb_convert_encoding($utf8string, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

***Good luck!! :)***

Answer (score 1):

- First check for UTF8 compatibility with this query. If it supports
  you should see the output as “Character_set_system”| “UTF8”
- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ‘character_set_system’;
- Now that being checked, alter the table and just modify the column,
  Posts in our above example and specify it as UTF8
- ALTER TABLE articles MODIFY Posts VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET UTF8;

Now, try to insert the telugu characters  value and save it.

Answer (score 1):

PLease check below mentioned solution.

When you use any regional language apart from English at that time your `Charset` will be `utf8` and set `Collection` = `utf8_general_ci`.

Let me know if it not works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your table, (select the table)Then  click on "structure" and then change the collation to "utf8_general_ci". After this add data and see, It worked for me